# how to splite excel data from vartical to horizontal using specific number of rows

Tags: excel

I need my file to be like this:

[image]

in the screen I choose the number of rows/column is 10

my  request id how to get my data  splited like the example  using specific number of rows/column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified one of my macros I use day-to-day.  You can play with this.
p.s.  Active cell must be the first cell of your data.

```
Sub split_by_ten()
If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
Exit Sub
Else
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i, j
    i = ActiveCell.Row
    j = 3
    Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 9, 1)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Cells(3, j).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        i = i + 10
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "done !"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it shows me this error https://i.imgur.com/8TzWSL6.png